# What is the output of gcc -c -Q -O --help=optimizers

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-flags

I am building an application with the -O flag (gcc).
But instead I would like to see which flags -O enables so that I can decide if I want to enable them or not. 
The output of

```
gcc -c -Q -O --help=optimizers
```

gives me a list like that:

```
-fgraphite-identity                   [disabled]
-fguess-branch-probability            [enabled]
-fhandle-exceptions
```

Some of the lines are disabled, some enabled and some are blank..
If I want to reproduce the compilation of -O with all flags what do I have to do? Do I have to leave out all the disabled flags? And what do I do with the flags which are left blank?

Comment: first google hit: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. This is actually where I got my command from:
"Depending on the target and how GCC was configured, a slightly different set of optimizations may be enabled at each -O level than those listed here. You can invoke GCC with -Q --help=optimizers to find out the exact set of optimizations that are enabled at each level. "

Comment: You can't duplicate the effect of `-O` with other options. From your link "Not all optimizations are controlled directly by a flag." ...  the "-f..." options are only adjustments to the overall optimisation level.

Comment: Ah.. Thanks! That makes sense.. should have read the documentation more carefully..